# Azure Active Directory Sign Up Redirects to Sign In

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I am creating a website using ASP.Net Core, and securing it with Azure AD B2C.

I have already implemented signing in and it is all working fine, but now I am attempting to setup sign up and it doesn't seem to be working.

My website setup is based on [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp).

In that example they do not use a sign up policy as they use a shared signup and signin policy (which I would prefer not to), but they do use an edit profile and reset password policy, the API methods can be seen on the [SessionController](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/Controllers/SessionController.cs).

I am trying to implement my signup endpoint in the same way like so:

```
var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" };
properties.Items[AzureAdB2COptions.PolicyAuthenticationProperty] = AzureAdB2COptions.SignUpPolicyId;
await HttpContext.Authentication.ChallengeAsync( OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, properties, ChallengeBehavior.Unauthorized);
```

However, when I go here I simply get redirected to the sign in page instead of the sign up page.

The sign up policy and the B2C directory in general is setup correctly as I am using it on another site with no issues.

Can anyone advise what may be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my OnRedirectToIdentityProvider method I had:

```
context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.Replace(defaultPolicy, policy);
```

As the IssuerAddress here is lower case it wasnt finding and changing the policy.

I updated it to:

```
context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.ToLower().Replace(defaultPolicy.ToLower(), policy.ToLower());
```

As is in the [latest version of the sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup.cs)

Comment: Hey Tom, can you flag your question as answered?

Comment: @Saca Yes, was going to do it myself once it allowed me :)